# Issues getting all data from an image file using Lua io.read('*a')

Tags: file-io, lua, jpeg

I'm trying to get all the data from image file (jpg/jpeg/gif/png/bmp etc.) use Lua's io.read() function, but I'm not having much luck as it only seems to read a small piece of the data.

As a side note all plain text files are being read just fine, so I'm assuming that the problem is with character encoding or some such thing.

Example:

```
local data
local fileHandle

fileHandle = io.open ( 'pic.jpg')
data = fileHandle:read('*a')

print(data)
```

Comment: Could it be that the file is being read as text?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're on Windows, open file as binary: `io.open('pic.jpg', 'rb')`.

Also it is a good idea to wrap `io.open()` in `assert()` to catch errors (or do handle them otherwise, of course).

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks so much, can't beleive it was this easy!